# How to handle content-length header in wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

currently i am using API Manager 4.0

If there is a content-lengh header in the Post Method, how can I set it up and test the API in the "try out" tab? I need help.

method: POST
url:   http://apihostip/GetPut?TYPE=GET&CLA=STRK
content:
:HEADER
TABLE=VERSION
VERSION
STRING
1.00
TABLE=VALID_OPER
SERIAL_NUM
STRING
ABCDEDF

But when try it out, come out the 411 error

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your requirement? The content-type header should not be set manually, the underneath transport library will set the correct content type based on the actual size of the payload. Why do you want to manually set the Content-type?

Answer (score 0):

From the API Publisher you can add a header to the resource.

1. Go to the API and click API Configurations under Develop section.
2. Click on the Resources.
3. Go the resource and add parameters.
4. From the parameters, click the Header type and fill the rest.
5. Deploy the API.
6. When you are trying out the API from the Swagger UI, it shows the header and you can provide any value to that header.

[image]